# mod_rewrite and relative HTML links

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I wrote a simple `mod_rewrite` to convert my ugly `URL`s:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule news\/([^\/]+)/([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)$     news.php?id=$2
  RewriteRule (.*)/images/(.*)$                     images/$2
  RewriteRule (.*)/css/(.*)$                            css/$2
  RewriteRule (.*)/js/(.*)$                         js/$2
</IfModule>
```

A problem immediately arose because all images, scripts, and styles are requested relative to the *fake* `URL`. So I had to append the next 3 `end-of-line` assertion for the `regex` and add the next 3 rules. What I am asking is that whether this approach is good or is it consuming too much resources? I know that this can be solved via absolute links but my *laziness* prompted me to try this solution which has a site-wide effect. Or is there a better solution?

One thing that was suggested was prepending slashes to the links. The problem is that the site can be accessed via two domains: `foo.com` and `bar.com/baz/qux/` so I really can't use that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also add a `<base href=""/>` to your html files, which saves you the images/css/js rewrite rules.

About "consuming too much resources" - when you get really really many accesses, it will fall on your feet for sure. But I doubt that you'll come into that traffic region.

Comment: That's just pure elegance. A solution in one line! 2mins to accept. Stupid restrictions =)